# How to handle mask images in Python

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library, photoshop

I have some images of the ground of an orchard, which look like these:

`image1.png`
[image]

`image2.png`
[image]

Now, I want to extract a region of chestnut from `image1.png` and then put it on `image2.png`.

So I made a mask image with Adobe Photoshop, and the result (exported as `mask.png`) looks like this:
[image]
You can see the selected region fits the edge of the chestnut tightly.

However, when I read the exported mask image with Python, the selected region did not fit the edge anymore. It was a rectangle that looked like this:

`result.png`
[image]

This is what I have done when reading the images and generating `result.png`.

```
import numpy as np 
from PIL import Image 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

# read image1.png
image1 = np.array(Image.open('image1.png').convert('RGB'))
# read mask.png
mask = np.array(Image.open('mask.png').convert('RGB')) 

# Boolean indices representing the selected region
region = np.all(img != 255, axis=-1)
# "region" has a shape of (height, width)
# so we have to add an axis corresponding to color channels
region = np.dstack([region, region, region])

plt.imshow(np.where(region, image1, 255))                                                           
plt.axis('off')
plt.savefig('result.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

Is there any tool by which I can use the mask image as it is (not like `result.png` but like `mask.png`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try OpenCV Python. Technically, your `mask.png` image is a RGBA color image with the RGB stand for Red-Green-Blue and A stand for transparency. When you used `np.array(Image.open('mask.png').convert('RGB'))`, you have removed the transparence channel away from the image.

```
import numpy as np 
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

mask = cv2.imread('mask.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

cv2.imwrite('result.png',mask)
```